# VB.net - Displaying chart with multiple Y axis

Tags: vb.net, charts

I am a bit new to vb.net. I have a requirement to display an excel chart containing 2 different data items on Y axis. I need to get the data from DB and bind to the chart. have the following code..

```
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection
        myConnection.Open()

        myCommand.CommandText = MainSQLStr
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

        Dim newSeries = New DataVisualization.Charting.Series()
        newSeries.ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column
        newSeries.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary

        newSeries.Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "Model", myReader, "count")

        Dim newSeries2 = New DataVisualization.Charting.Series()
        newSeries2.ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column
        newSeries2.Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "Model", myReader, "ModelValue")

        Chart1.Series.Add(newSeries)

        Chart1.Series.Add(newSeries2)
```

The problem is I am seeing the graph with only one data series. The second series is missing. I am  Not sure, what I am missing. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!